# SwiperJS implementation

Tags: swiper.js

I need some help on how to get slides to slide across on the screen. I have implemented swiperJS with the basic requirements but on get the slides but do do scroll horizontally. What is the problem? Thanks

I did the following but unable to get the slides sliding across.

Comment: `I did the following` we need to see what you had done and see what is not working fine, please provide your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.